# Can't update software

Tags: 14.04

I am new to Linux, I have 14.04 installed, when I'm trying to download from software center I click install and the progress bar only go's half way across and thats it nothing happens after that. What do I do?

Comment: Can you install from terminal?

Comment: No, nothing happens

Comment: Where does it get stuck when installing the software via `apt-get`?

Comment: It seems to have fixed it self, because its working again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about updating software then I recommend just opening a terminal and running `sudo apt-get upgrade` to update all packages. If you are talking about installing something I would recommend finding the package name and typing `sudo apt-get install [package name]` as I have found the terminal to be a lot more reliable and it provides and installation log should something hang.